# Tomcat7 Windows Service doesn't start

Tags: windows-services, tomcat7

I would like to build a tomcat 7 windows service with the following command:

```
tomcat7 //IS//Tomcat7 --DisplayName="Informatica ActiveVOS Server" --Install="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.93\bin\tomcat7.exe" --Jvm=auto --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm --StartClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams=start --StopClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopParams=stop
```

The service is correctly created but it doesn't even start correctly

[image]

If I use the command `service.bat install` I'm obliged to use a display name with out space...but it starts...is there any way to fix this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after digging into service.bat I found that tomcat7.exe is launched too but with extended parameters numbers :
The EXECUTABLE parameters refers to tomcat7.exe file path.

What I've done, in the service.bat I changed the values of SERVICE_NAME and DISPLAYNAME to my target. And voila !

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% ^
    --Description "Apache Tomcat 7.0.93 Server - https://tomcat.apache.org/" ^
    --DisplayName "%DISPLAYNAME%" ^
    --Install "%EXECUTABLE%" ^
    --LogPath "%CATALINA_BASE%\logs" ^
    --StdOutput auto ^
    --StdError auto ^
    --Classpath "%CLASSPATH%" ^
    --Jvm "%JVM%" ^
    --StartMode jvm ^
    --StopMode jvm ^
    --StartPath "%CATALINA_HOME%" ^
    --StopPath "%CATALINA_HOME%" ^
    --StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap ^
    --StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap ^
    --StartParams start ^
    --StopParams stop ^
    --JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-D%ENDORSED_PROP%=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed;-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" ^
    --JvmOptions9 "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED#--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED#--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED" ^
    --JvmMs 128 ^
    --JvmMx 256
```